# Help in understanding an exercise on observable / measurement

Tags: quantum-state, measurement

I'm working through Quantum Computing for Computer Scientists (Yanofsky & Mannucci, 2008), and am getting a little confused about **Observables**. From what I understand an observable is a question represented by a hermitian matrix. But that's as far as it goes. When we **use** an observable to make a **measurement** we obtain a real result, which can change the state space $|\Psi\rangle$. There is mention in the book that "after an observation" (presumably after a measurement is taken) then the result should be an eigenvalue, and the state of the system should collapse into the state which is the eigenvector corresponding to that eigenvalue.

> Then, in example 4.3.1 on p.126 the authors use the observable
>   $$\Omega=\begin{bmatrix}-1&-i\\i&1\end{bmatrix},$$
>   which they state has eigenvalues $\lambda_1=-\sqrt{2}$ and $\lambda_2=\sqrt{2}$, with corresponding eigenvectors $|e_1\rangle=[-0.923i,-0.382]^T$ and $|e_2\rangle=[-0.382,0.923i]^T$.
>
> It goes on to say "now, let us suppose that afer an observation of $\Omega$ on $|\Psi\rangle=\frac{1}{2}[1,1]^T$, the actual value observed is $\lambda_1$. The system has "collapsed" from $|\Psi\rangle$ to $|e_1\rangle$.

I'm finding it difficult to understand this. Do the authors mean to perform a measurement, i.e.

$$\Omega|\Psi\rangle=\begin{bmatrix}-1&-i\\i&1\end{bmatrix}\frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
 -\frac{i}{2}-\frac{1}{2} \\
 \frac{i}{2}+\frac{1}{2} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

But then how have we observed $\lambda_1=\sqrt{2}$ ?

I think I've got the wrong end of the stick because the authors say "now, let us **suppose** that after an observation...," so maybe there is no calculation to be made, but it's very confusing.

Can anybody help me understand this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you give an observable, such as $\Omega$, that is used to define the measurement basis. It is not something that you would usually use to directly perform calculations (you can, and for $2\times 2$ matrices, we often do, as I'll detail below).

Normally, you want to take your observable, $\Omega$, and find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors. More specifically, you want projectors onto the different eigenspaces (this distinction is important if your matrix has degeneracy). So, we take
$$
P_1=|e_1\rangle\langle e_1|,\qquad P_2=|e_2\rangle\langle e_2|.
$$
In a sense, the eigenvalues are irrelevant, and hence so is $\Omega$. Our outcome is a state
$$
|\Phi_i\rangle=P_i|\Psi\rangle,
$$
up to normalisation (for rank 1 projectors, as here, the renormalised version is just $|e_i\rangle$), and the probability of getting outcome $i$ is $\langle\Phi_i|\Phi_i\rangle$. Note that you have to explicitly describe the branching outcomes (here, two different possibilities, with different probabilities). One simple calculation such as a matrix multiplication can't give you that.

Now, it turns out that you *can* use the matrix $\Omega$ directly if you want. This is because, by completeness,
$$
\sum_iP_i=I,
$$
and we know that $\Omega=\sqrt{2}(-P_1+P_2)$. Hence, we can rearrange for $P_1$:
$$
P_1=\frac{1}{2}(I-\Omega/\sqrt{2}),
$$
and we can perform the same calculation as previously without having directly calculated the eigenvectors first. There's always a trick like this for $2\times 2$ matrices. For $n\times n$ matrices, you'd probably have to describe each of your projectors as a polynomial in $\Omega$ up to a power $n-1$, which is why we don't usually do this for anything other than $2\times 2$ matrices - it just gets more messy.

Comment: Thank you. So as I now understand it, our observable $\Omega$ is simply a matrix representation of our question, which we don't really compute with at all. What matters is $\Omega$'s eigenvectors $|e_i\rangle$, which become our basis for measurement of our quantum system. To actually perform a calculation (measure) we work out $P_i=|e_i\rangle\langle e_i|\in M_{n,n}(\mathbb{C})$, and then then compute the outcomes as $|\Phi_i\rangle=P_i|\Psi\rangle$, the probability of getting each of which is $\langle\Phi_i|\Phi_i\rangle$.

Comment: @Pixel Yes, exactly.

Comment: @DaftWullie "*In a sense, the eigenvalues are irrelevant,*" ah! I feel like my rumblings in [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/482768/58382) have been vindicated =)